# Asp.net password encryption and decryption with salt

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, encryption

I am trying to pull an encrypted password from a table but am receiving this error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '84p37U29dna08XhUdV+bhQ==' to data type int.

Where the value is my encrypted password. I don't understand why there is this error. The code breaks at the line: **dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);**

```
protected bool attemptLogin(String username, String password)
    {
        bool validLogin = false;

        String sql = "SELECT Users.username, Passwords.password " +
                     "FROM Users INNER JOIN Passwords ON Users.userID = Passwords.password " +
                     "WHERE Users.username = @username";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        // Set of Tables (in this instance, just one)
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        // First Table in DataSet
        DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];

        // Get value of password (should be in encrypted form)
        String dbPassword = table.Rows[0]["password"].ToString();

        // Decrypt password
        String decryptedPassword = decryptText("", dbPassword);
        if (decryptedPassword.Equals(password))
        {
            validLogin = true;
        }

        return validLogin;
    }
```

Comment: Ignoring the error you are getting, your technique is fundamentally flawed. you DO NOT decrypt passwords! you store a salted hash, add salt and hash a given password and compare to that value stored.

Comment: @MitchWheat you don't need to store a salted hash however. I use a combination of Buffer.BlockCopy and BitConverter, along with secure hash/salt generators, to store only a hash of the password which is in fact a hash of a hash.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath As soon as all the information is stored in a single field, you're vulnerable again to attacks salting aims to solve (namely, rainbow tables).

Comment: @cFrozenDeath : Incorrect. I hope you haven't implemented as you describe. Please see Rob's comment.

Comment: To Rob and @MitchWheat, I wanted to see what people thinks on that, so I created this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115953/secure-password-hashing-is-this-overkill

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: I'm not reviewing code where the technique you describe is just plain wrong!!

Comment: @MitchWheat How can you know something is wrong without knowing what it is? I doubt Microsoft would create such an insecure system as you describe. And what I do is very similar to what Microsoft does in ASP.NET.

Comment: " How can you know something is wrong without knowing what it is?" - I'm going by your 'advice' in original comment. It shows a lack of understanding of good security practices. Just because Microsoft do it in some crappy example (probably written by an intern) does not make it good or best practice!!

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: ironically, the code you posted on codereview saves a salted hash, which is fine. The pre-hash of the password is redundant.

Comment: @JimFlood My point was that it's all stored in one single cell. The pre-hash is because it originally was a desktop program that sent the password pre-hashed and the server finished the hashing. Would you suggest to remove that?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath No, I think it's fine as is. I would think that Rob and Mitch Wheat would also agree that it's fine. Adding the salt and iterations was a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

`INNER JOIN Passwords ON Users.userID = Passwords.password`

You're attempting to join UserID (int) to the Password (nvarchar).